# Can enclitics be chained?

Tags: morphology, enclitic

I am active in a small Latin Discord group; a member brought up a question concerning the validity of the following phrase with chained enclitics:

> *Valēsneque?*
>   *(with the enclitics distinguished) Valēs-ne-que?*

I assume that their intent was to convey something that fell around the following sentiments; it was not difficult for me to clearly interpret what he was trying to say:

> *And how are you?*
>   *And are you [doing] well?*
>   *etc.*

However, I asserted that it was *not* valid, and offered a potentially suitable alternative like *"et ut valēs?"*; another member offered the equally suitable  *"atque ut valēs?"*.

I assumed that *valēsneque* was invalid largely based on two reasons: one, the fact that, other than words with unremovable enclitics that have taken on a separate meaning (see: *quīcumque, quaecumque, quodcumque* and others like it), I have never encountered any instance of chained enclitics anywhere; and secondly, the fact that Latin is classified as a fusional language, and that if *valēsneque* was indeed valid, it would be a potentially interesting case of agglutination in a fusional language.

This leads me to my primary question: is the chaining of enclitics *-que, -ve, -ne* in sequences like *valēsneque* valid or not?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The question in the title ("Can enclitics be chained?") is broader than the one you end the body with ("Can -ne, -que, -ve be chained?").

1. The answer to the first question (assuming we can agree on a definition of an enclitic) is "yes." Consider one common but limited-use enclitic that you didn't bring up: *-cum* after certain pronouns. *-cumque* is quite common--and I don't just mean words like *quicumque*. Here's Cicero:

   > **tecumque** et ero tantum quantum patietur utriusque aetas et valetudo, et, si esse una    minus poterimus quam volemus, animorum tamen coniunctione iisdemque studiis ita fruemur ut numquam non una esse videamur. (*Epistulae ad Familiares* 5.13)
2. As for the second question, I agree with Joonas's answer: a corpus search only reveals false positives for the six combinations of -que, -ne, and -ve.

Answer (score 10):

Playing with [a corpus search tool](http://latin.packhum.org/search) brought up no examples of *-quene* or *-neque* in the intended sense.
If chaining was admissible, I would expect to see attestations with *-que* and *-ne*, the most common enclitics.
Therefore I would argue that chaining of enclitics is not good classical Latin, but it is readily understandable in modern use.

Comment: I mentioned it in my answer, but perhaps I'm missing something obvious: how did you sift through the results for "neque#" to determine that they were all false positives? That definitely seems like the most promising combination

Comment: @brianpck To screen off the word *neque*, I searched for things like "sneque#" and similarly for some other common final letters beside S. I didn't go through the entire alphabet, though. I wish there was a way to search for "neque# but not #neque#"...

Comment: I didn't think of that! You're right that that eliminates the false positives!